# Flex - search for string in TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, search, air, adobe

I have a TextArea that allows user input. I also have TextInput that the user can type a string into and I want to be able to search through the TextArea for the string in the TextInput. I've never done anything like this before, searching for strings, so I don't know which functions to use or how to go about it.

Could someone please explain how to do this, or even give a small code snippet showing the process involved. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
protected function searchBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                text = mainTextField.text;
                search_Str = searchTxt.text;

                var search_result:int = text.search(search_Str);
                trace(search_result);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First retrieve the texts from the text area and input field, for example:

```
var text       = $('#textarea_id').val();
var search_str = $('#input_id').val();
```

And then we'll do the seach:

```
var search_result = text.search(search_str);
```

Now `search_result` has the beginning index of the `search_str` in the `text`, or -1 if the `search_str` wasn't found.

Comment: Darn, beat me to it. +1 for this

Comment: Huh? Am I missing something here? This question is about Flex, yet the answer seems to be using some JS library...

Comment: Glad to help. It's using JQuery to select the text elements, but you can do that also with plain javascript (document.getElementById()), if Flex does not use JQuery (I'v never used is, so dunno).

Comment: I easily converted the idea to Actionscript for Flex. This was a huge help! :D

Comment: I've updated my post with the code I'm using for anyone that's interested.

Comment: Oh, i confused Flex with Adobe Edge (HTML5 framework). Well, luckily Actionscript is almost same as JS. :)